# form button must change color when user place mouse pointer over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have the following form :

```
<form  action="login_form.php"   method="POST"   id="login_form">  
  Email  <input name="email" type="text" size="25" placeholder="type your email"/>
  Password  <input name="password" type="text" size="25" placeholder="type your password" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" style="background:url('img/button-go.png') no-repeat;  width:68px;  height:27px;  border:none;  cursor:pointer;    "/>     
</form>
```

As you can see, I use as a button in my form an image called `button-go.png`. I have another button called `button-go_light.png`. All I want is when the user place mouse pointer above form button called `button-go.png` to change to `button-go_light.png`. What is the easier way to do this, that works in all explorers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in **css** you want this:    **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k4q5D/)**

```
.btn{
    background-image: url('button-go.png');
}

.btn:hover{
    background-image: url('button-go_light.png');
}
```

Comment: +1 Definitely the simplest way to do this. And cross-browser as OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:hover` inline as shown below:

```
<form  action="login_form.php"   method="POST"   id="login_form">
  Email  <input name="email" type="text" size="25" placeholder="type your email"/>
  Password  <input name="password" type="text" size="25" placeholder="type your password" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" style="{background:url('img/button-go.png') no-repeat;  width:68px;  height:27px;  border:none;  cursor:pointer;    }:hover {background:url('img/button-go_light.png');}"/>     
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` for `<input>` won't work in IE6 and below - as `:hover` works only for links there. So, if you also support IE6- you'll have to use a JS-polyfill in case you want `<input>`s to change bg-image on hover.